# PL/SQL LOOP increment unpredictable result

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Just trying to insert values into table using loop.

The code for loop is next

```
DECLARE
ID_src number;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..10000
  LOOP
    ID_src := i;
       INSERT INTO src_facts values (ID_src);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

From my view output should be:

```
1
2
3
...
10000
```

But I reviewed unpredictable result. It is:

[image]

Can you explain what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean that the table data isn't sorted 1,2,3,...,10000?  There is no reason why it should be, or should be returned in sorted order - unless you explicitly sort it using ORDER BY.  In SQL Developer you can click on the column heading to sort the data.  Tables are not inherently sorted.

Answer (score 1):

The result is not unpredictable.  You just need `order by`:

```
select *
from src_facts
order by id_src;
```

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Unless you include an `ORDER BY`, there is no guarantee of the order of the rows in the result set.